# Elastic Beanstalk Instance Detect When Terminating

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node.js app and would like each EC2 instance to be able to detect when the instance is about to be terminated so that it may perform some cleanup and release any resources.

Is there any way from within Node.js for such an instance to know that it is about to be terminated?

Comment: Even if they do provide a lifecycle hook / .ebextension task for this, it would not be ideal to rely on this hook because cloud instances can always fail, sometimes randomly and without warning. Maybe look into storing state somewhere out of memory, like in a redis instance or something.

Comment: True, can't always cleanup. I'm just trying to do what I can and wasn't sure if there was something simple I missed in the docs.

Comment: There still might be, but it wasn't obvious to me either